# How can I write dynamically remove condition in Where clause condition

Tags: sql, dynamic, conditional-statements

I have a query as follows:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE USER_ID = ?`

And then I set the `USER_ID` using a prepared statement. Is there a way to use the same query and prepared statement to retrieve data without any filtering? Something like the followinf maybe?

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE USER_ID = *`

I want to use the same query and prepared statement-setting method to get data equivalent to `SELECT * FROM mytable`

I went through the sql `ANY` and `ALL` but they don't seem to cater my problem.

Comment: Is `USER_ID` your dynamical parameter?

Comment: Yes it is retrieved during runtime

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use a condition like this.

Set parameter as a default value or check `@USER_ID`, In this sample, I set default value as `NULL`. If you want to get all data you can set `@USER_ID` as `NULL`, otherwise query by `userID`

```
DECLARE @USER_ID INT = NULL;

SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE (@USER_ID IS NULL) OR USER_ID = @USER_ID
```

Here is a sample from sql-server

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bcbf1e78b5c511f95604658c6e05a7d7)